# How to setup redislite in specific port:6379

Tags: pythonanywhere, stackexchange.redis, node-redis, redislabs

I am learning django channels in pythonanywhere and pythonanywhere support redislite instead of redis.

so i want to setup redislite to port 6379
exactly like in redis command:**redis-server --port 6379**

I don't seem to find exact answer.
Any answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's not redislite, that's redis. redislite is just a module that you import and use.